# cameraX preview Skews when I tilt my device sideways(Left or right) using GlSurfaceView

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-camerax, glsurfaceview

I am making a camera filter app, for that I am using opengles and CameraX, when I use PreviewView everything works fine but when I use GlSurfaceView the preview starts to skew as I move my device sideways.

[image: image example for skewing of camera output]

1. I am creating a texture in the renderer
2. creating a surface texture out of the texture
3. creating a surface provider from that surface texture
4. finally providing this surface provider to the CameraX.

This way I am allowing cameraX to provide preview on the texture  which I am manipulating through opengles to create colour filters.

Everything works just when I tilt the phone the image starts skewing and the skew increases as the angle of tilt increases.

Comment: Is there a reason that you want to use GLSurfaceView instead of PreviewView?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Xi张熹 Basically I don't know how to connect OpenGL to PreviewView. So I basically used GlSurfaceView because I can connect it to a renderer and write custom gles code for it

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [SurfaceProcessor](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/SurfaceProcessor) API. It's designed for injecting things like OpenGL renderer into CameraX pipeline. It's compatible with `PreviewView`. You can find a sample code here: https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/camera/camera-core/src/main/java/androidx/camera/core/processing/DefaultSurfaceProcessor.java